# VBA Excel: How to add items for duplicates data in range excel with vba

Tags: vba, excel

I want to use VBA to insert items in ITEM column with data source is in Number column like below, count number of items and add number from 1 to number counts. can you help me?

```
Number  Item
24811395    1
24811396    1
24811401    1
24811401    2
24811402    1
24811408    1
24811408    2
24811408    3
24811408    4
```

Comment: Really want VBA only? this can be easily done with excel formula

Answer (score 1):

Use the formula in `B2` as in image below and drag throughout the range,

`=COUNTIF($A$2:$A2,A2)`

[image]